# Rate the app with SKStoreReviewController only or alternatives in iOS

Tags: ios, review, skstorereviewcontroller

Apple now has `SKStoreReviewController` class, that gives developers possibility to prompt rating dialog for the app easily.

After reading this article (https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/09/app-rating-custom-prompts-app-store-banned/) I confused a bit. Now we have to use only this class to provide interface for rating the app. But I have couple of questions, that I can't find the answer yet:

1. This class was first introduced in iOS 10.3, but I support earlier versions (starting with 8.0). How can I solve the problem for earlier versions of iOS?
2. I have 2 places in the app for ratings. First is prompt after number of launches (this will be safely replaced with new class with no problems). Second is "*Rate us*" button in app's menu. This button opens the AppStore with the app's page there using `openURL:` method. Can this functionality be left (I guess, this is not rating prompt, this is user choose)? Does someone pass the Apple's review with similar functionality?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same functionality (SKStoreReviewController and a Rate Us button).

Since implementing SKStoreReviewController and submitting a few updates, the app hasn't been rejected by Apple for including a "Rate us" button.

However, thats not to say that Apple won't change their mind once iOS 11 is released.

If anything changes in the mean time, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater)

The library supports iOS 4.0+ using SKStoreReviewController in iOS 10.3+. Besides it has the logic to show the review according to events, uses or days.